# Scala 2.13: Passing an explicit array value to a Scala varargs method is deprecated

Tags: scala, playframework, twirl

I am migrating to Scala 2.13.

`args: (Symbol, String)*` in a Play Twirl template gives me this warning:

> Passing an explicit array value to a Scala varargs method is deprecated (since 2.13.0) and will result in a defensive copy; Use the more efficient non-copying ArraySeq.unsafeWrapArray or an explicit toIndexedSeq call

Here is the whole template:

```
@(action: play.api.mvc.Call, args: (Symbol, String)*)(body: => Html)
<form  method="@action.method"
  @toHtmlArgs(args.toMap)>
  @body
</form>
```

Here is how this function is called:

```
@helper.formRelative(action = ..., Symbol("id") -> "assignForm", Symbol("class") -> "ui form") { ..body.. }
```

As I use this in a lot of places, is there **a way to resolve this without changing the signature?**

I tried different things, like:

- add `toSeq`: `@toHtmlArgs(args.toSeq.toMap)`
- also with removing `@toHtmlArgs(args.toMap)` the warning showed up.

Comment: It seems he problem isn't with `toHtmlArgs`, it's with the code calling the template.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I added an example to my question on how I use this template.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested, use `scala.collection.immutable.ArraySeq.unsafeWrapArray` : pass this as `args`:

```
unsafeWrapArray(Array(Symbol("id") -> "assignForm", Symbol("class") -> "ui form")):_*
```